# Formula To Evaluate from Left to Right

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have three tabs in my Google Spreadsheet:
Everything, Calendar Past and Present, and Calendar Future.

Tab Everything has all the data.  Calendar Past and Present shows attendance from today and into the past.  These tabs function like they should.  I would like Calendar Future to show from tomorrow and further into the future for scheduled days off.

**Everything Tab:**
[image: Everything]

**Calendar Present and Past Tab:**
[image: Present and Past]

**Calendar Future Tab:**
[image]

Note that in the Calendar Future Tab the data is reversed and is now reading from Left to Right.
Calendar Past and Present is populated by formulas which concatenate the employee and his status.

This is the formula I am using in Calendar Past and Present.

> =IFERROR(IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(B3),Days_Off!$C$2:$C,Days_Off!$D$2:$D))=FALSE,XLOOKUP(DATEVALUE(B3),Days_Off!$C$2:$C,Days_Off!$A$2:$A),ARRAYFORMULA("
> " &
> FILTER(Everything!$A$2:$A,(NOT(REGEXMATCH(Everything!GP2:GP,"^Here")))*(Everything!GP2:GP<>"")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(Everything!GP2:GP,"Day
> Off")))) & "     " &
> FILTER(Everything!GP2:GP,(NOT(REGEXMATCH(Everything!GP2:GP,"^Here")))*(Everything!GP2:GP<>"")*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(Everything!GP2:GP,"Day
> Off")))))),"")

How would I do the same for the Future Tab without having to manually edit each formula?  (My calendar reads nine months into the future.  I basically need to reverse the formulas in the Calendar Past and Present Tab.

Is this possible with formula or script?

Comment: What need to be different in each formula? Is it just that `Everything!GP2:GP` needs to be going the other direction when you pull the formulas across in the Future tab?

Comment: Can you please share a dummy sheet/s with data as well as your desired output? it will be easier to replicate and understand your concern.

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios, that is correct.

Comment: @ScriptingNovice You may be able to get what you need with [offset](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379?hl=en), I haven't tried this, but maybe something like `offset(Everything!GP2:GP,,-1*column(a1))` to calculate the correct range (note skipping the second argument of offset)

Comment: I will look into it, thank you.  I would have thought that I could write in two formulas and drag the cells and Google Sheets would recognize the pattern.

Comment: Went another route that ended up being easy enough.  Broke "Everything" sheet into Past and Present and into Future with Future reading Left to Right to begin with.  This made it easier to apply the formulas and achieve the results.  Thank you all for your interest and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took "Everything" sheet and broke it into two separate sheets:  "Everything Past and Present" and "Everything Future".  I kept the structure of "Everything Past and Present" the same, but ran the dates from left to right in "Everything Future".  I copied and pasted the formulas from "Calendar Past and Present Tab" and the data all evaluated correctly.

After trying a lot of different options I came across through a Google search, this seemed to be the most effective (and least mind-numbing) solution.